# arm-gcc optimization don't remove functions with same content

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, arm, bare-metal

I'm expecting that gcc remove same functions and keep only one from code, but not possible with any type of optimization (-O1, -O2, -O3, -Os, -Ofast, ..)

I use gcc v4.9.3 and here is very minimal code:

```
__attribute__((weak)) void f1() { while (1); }
__attribute__((weak)) void f2() { while (1); }
__attribute__((weak)) void f3() { while (1); }

__attribute__((section(".vect"), used)) void (*f[])() = {
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f1,
};
```

Then this linker script:

```
SECTIONS {
    .text : {
        *(.vect)
        *(.text)
    }
}
```

And compile it with:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -O1 -mthumb -nostartfiles -T test.ld test.c -o test.elf
```

When I look into disassembly I see all functions:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -S test.elf

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <f>:
   0:   11 00 00 00 15 00 00 00 19 00 00 00 11 00 00 00     ................

00000010 <f1>:
  10:   e7fe        b.n 10 <f1>
  12:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

00000014 <f2>:
  14:   e7fe        b.n 14 <f2>
  16:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

00000018 <f3>:
  18:   e7fe        b.n 18 <f3>
  1a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
```

Is this a problem of gcc or is there a way to optimize this?

thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol maybe this gcc specific "esoteric" feature messes up the optimization. And indeed - if it were optimizing this and a strong symbol would replace one of those functions, how would that work?

Comment: This makes sense.  Maybe you want **alias** instead.  The compiler has no idea if you will or won't reference the functions externally.

Comment: BitTickler: I removed all week symbols but with no success

Comment: artless noise: Thanks, week alias is working, I use something like this:
`void __f() { while (1); }`
`__attribute__((weak, alias("__f"))) void f1();`...